# Win32 API Call in Haskell?

Tags: python, haskell

How might I replicate this bit of of Python in Haskell? I've been able to master all the other process launching bits, but this one is elusive - it doesn't seem to be in api of any existing packages. The closest thing I can find is [this example](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/06/ffi-calling-into-kernel32dll.html) but I'm having a hard time adapting it.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetErrorMode(2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Foreign_Function_Interface](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Calling_conventions) article mentions `stdcall` keyword for foreign import statements. In your case this would look like

```
import System.Win32.Types (DWORD)

foreign import stdcall unsafe "SetErrorMode"
    win32_setErrorMode :: DWORD -> IO DWORD
```

Comment: Do I need anything else, like the windows.h import?

Comment: For the snippet above you shouldn't need anything else.